# FastAPI fileupload to S3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3

I am writing a FastAPI endpoint to upload a file to S3 Object Store. Following is the code snippet. However, I get an exception *"expected string or bytes-like object"*

I don't want to save the file temporarily and then upload it.

I reead in FastAPI documentation that the UploadFile has file attribute which is an *"actual Python file (SpooledTemporaryFile) that you can pass directly to other functions or libraries that expect a "file-like" object"*. Since the upload_fileobj function of boto3 expects a string or bytes-like argument, I converted the file-like object to BytesIO object using the _file attribute of the SpooledTemporaryFile. But still the error *"expected string or bytes-like object"*

Any pointers will be appreciated.

```
@app.post("/uploadFile")
async def upload_file(fileobject: UploadFile = File(...),filename: str = Body(default=None),key: str = Body(default=None),):
extension = fileobject.filename.rsplit(".", 1)[1].lower()
if key is None:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=400, MissingError="Key is missing")
if filename is None:
    filename = fileobject.filename
if fileobject.filename.endswith(tuple(ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS)):    
    data = (
        fileobject.file._file
    )  # Using _file attribute convert tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile to io.BytesIO
    try:
        # Upload the file to Spaces
        upload_result = await client.upload_fileobj(
            data,
            BUCKET,
            f"{key}/{filename}",
            ExtraArgs={
                "ACL": "public",
                "ContentType": FILE_CONTENT_TYPES[extension],
            },
        )
        if upload_result:
            object_url = f"{OBJ_URL}/{key}/{file.filename}"
            doc = [{"file_url": object_url}]
        else:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Failed to upload in S3")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Exception while uploading file - {e}")
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=400, detail=f"Exception {e} while uploading the file"
        )
else:
    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=400, detail=f"File of type {extension} is not allowed"
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, but the issue was with the bucket name, mine was None/empty, the error message is rather annoying, the bucket should be a non empty string.